# How to send GET request with Oauth1 library with duplicates parameters headers?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

First time posting but I found many solutions over the years, so thanks to the people who provide help.

I am trying to send a GET request with OAuth1.0 to an API from a Google-apps-script with multiple paramaters sharing the same name.

Is there a way to do it using the OAuth1 Library ? 
([link](https://script.google.com/a/veolia.com/d/1CXDCY5sqT9ph64fFwSzVtXnbjpSfWdRymafDrtIZ7Z_hwysTY7IIhi7s/edit?usp=drive_web))

I managed to make it work with single parameters names.

```
var get_documents_params = [
["Name","value"],
['OtherName','value'],
];
```

The following code with duplicate parameters name gets the error "The supplied authentication is invalid: Invalid signature".
The API can receive same name parameters as my request works when using [postman](http://getpostman.com)

```
var service = getService();


var get_documents_params = [
["SameName","value1"],
['SameName','value2'],
];

var url = "https://the_API_url.com";


var query_params = '?';


query_params += encodeURIComponent(get_documents_params[0][0]) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(get_documents_params[0][1]) + '&';

query_params += encodeURIComponent(get_documents_params[1][0]) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(get_documents_params[1][1]);

var params = {
    'method': 'GET', 
    'Accept':'application/json',
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true
    };

  var response = service.fetch(url+query_params, params);


________

Logger.log(url+query_params);
// shows : "https://the_API_url.com?SameName=value1&SameName=value2"
_________


function getService() {
  return OAuth1.createService('API_GET')
      // Set the consumer key and secret.
      .setConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY)
      .setConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET)

      .setAccessToken(TOKEN, TOKEN_SECRET);

}
```

---

Postman settings

```
GET https://the_API_url.com?SameName=value1&SameName=value2
HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Authorization: OAuth 
oauth_consumer_key="consumer_key",oauth_token="consumer_token",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1572334760",oauth_nonce="XXXXX",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="XXXXX"
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.19.0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: XXXXXX
Host: the_API_url.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: ajs_anonymous_id=XXXXX; mp_a6b59f6f7db3f0bbdef2c0450a4b4694_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%2216d9174a2537c6-0ccd361fcb3648-6a40291d-1fa400-16d9174a25460e%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%7D
Connection: keep-alive
```

---

I expect to receive a JSon object as it works when sending a request with one single use of parameters names.

Comment: In your situation, as the query parameter, when `?Name=value&OtherName=value` is used for Google Apps Script, it  works fine. But when `?SameName=value1&SameName=value2` is used, it doesn't work. On the other hand, in the case of postman, both `?Name=value&OtherName=value` and `?SameName=value1&SameName=value2` work fine. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In order to correctly understand about the differences between Google Apps Script and postman, can you provide the detail setting information of postman? If you can do, please add it to your question. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I've added the info. For more details, the signature used by default in the Oauth1.0 library is also HMAC-SHA1

Comment: I believe I found half the solution, the library interprets the url as an object and therefore overwrites values for keys sharing the same name. I believe the object doesn't get the proper signature as it might be corrupted through the script flow

Comment: You were right about modifying the headers format but it doesn't solve my issue. My problem is that the function fetch() only accept single use of parameters name.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation. When I confirmed [the script](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth1/blob/master/dist/OAuth1.gs), the URL is requested as `https://the_API_url.com?SameName=value1&SameName=value2`. But I'm not sure whether this is the reason of your issue. I deeply apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: Please don't be sorry and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the function service.fetch() only accepts parameters name with one single use, as the 'url' param is interpreted as an object through the library OAuth1.0. An object overwrites every name that is used more than once.